# Cannot create relation field on a composite type

Tags: mongodb, prisma

Given a schema such as:

```
model User {
  id   String @id @map("_id")
  shop Shop
  ...
}

model ItemCategory {
  id         String                 @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name       String
  ...
}

type Shop {
  items Item[]
  ...
}

type Item {
  name     String
  category   ItemCategory      @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId String            @map("category") @db.ObjectId
  ...
}
```

Prisma complains that `Defining "@relation" attribute for a field in a composite type is not allowed`. What would be an alternative way of achieving the same result, if there is any?